# How to fetch LinkedIn connections/Friends/Contacts in iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, linkedin-api

I want to fetch all my friends from my LinkedIn profile. Please suggest me any tutorial.

My code is :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,Positions)"];
OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                               consumer:self.oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                                                  token:self.oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                                               callback:nil
                                                      signatureProvider:nil];

[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];

OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(profileApiCallResult:didFinish:)
              didFailSelector:@selector(profileApiCallResult:didFail:)];
```

Comment: did you try LinkedIn iOS SDK : http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2856 ?

Comment: also other API : https://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Comment: I want the all friends list of LinkedIn

Comment: Try the API first . We will not help before you try anything

Comment: I have implement this, Now I am able to fetch all my connections, But I am not able to fetch email address of my connections.Please help me. It become road blocker.

Comment: can you show your codes ?

Comment: Sorry for late replying. I have edit my message with code. Please check this.

Comment: @GaganAggarwal i have same issue like u plz help me yar.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for connections:[For request part see this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785452/linkedin-integration-r-network-and-w-messages-request-not-working-together-in-io/17832085#17832085)

```
- (void)connectionsApiCallResult:(LOAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinish:(NSData *)data
    {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"connectionsApiCallResult====%@",responseBody);

        [responseBody release];
    }

    - (void)connectionsApiCallResult:(LOAServiceTicket *)ticket didFail:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);

    }

    -(void)GetConnectionsCall
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(headline,first-name,last-name,picture-url,id)"];

        LOAMutableURLRequest *request =
        [[LOAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                        consumer:self.consumer
                                           token:TestAccessToken
                                        callback:nil
                               signatureProvider:nil];

        [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];

        LOADataFetcher *fetcher = [[[LOADataFetcher alloc] init] autorelease];
        [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                             delegate:self
                    didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFinish:)
                      didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFail:)];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps

1. first go to https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer edit your App scope , make sure you have checked the r_network scope .
2. Then go to **OAuthLoginView** of you project , then go to **-(void) requestTokenFromProvider** method .

edit you scope in below lines .

```
OARequestParameter *nameParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"scope"
value:@"r_fullprofile+rw_nus+r_network"];

OARequestParameter * scopeParameter=[OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"scope" 
value:@"r_fullprofile rw_nus r_network"];
```