# LinkedIn Integration r_network and w_messages request not working together in iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, linkedin-api

I have done LinkedIn integration and I have to send message to particular users.For that first I am fetching connections and then sending messages.

```
(void)requestTokenFromProvider { OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestTokenURL consumer:self.consumer token:nil callback:linkedInCallbackURL signatureProvider:nil] autorelease];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

OARequestParameter *nameParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"scope" value:@"r_basicprofile+w_messages+r_network"];

NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameParam, nil]; [request setParameters:params];

OARequestParameter * scopeParameter=[OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"scope" value:@"r_basicprofile"];

[request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:scopeParameter]];

OARequestParameter * networkParameter=[OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"scope" value:@"w_messages"];

[request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:networkParameter]];

OARequestParameter * netParameter=[OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"scope" value:@"r_network"];

[request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:netParameter]];

OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[[OADataFetcher alloc] init] autorelease]; [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFinish:) didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFail:)]; }
```

When I am sending request for both w_messages and r_network then one of them is not working,getting output as "Access To connections Denied" Or "Access to sending invitation denied."

If I use both separately with r_basicprofile then they are working fine but when I use them together one of them's access is denied.I am not getting any clue.Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got the solution.On request part I need to pass like this.

```
OARequestParameter *nameParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"scope" value:@"r_basicprofile+w_messages+r_network"];

 NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameParam, nil];

 [request setParameters:params];

 OARequestParameter * scopeParameter=[OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"scope" value:@"r_basicprofile w_messages r_network"];

[request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:scopeParameter]];
```

Comment: Yes you can ask about the permissions that is allowed here ...https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication...just pass them as above where I have passed three requests.

Comment: By default they allow firstname,lastname,headline and site-standard-profile-request/url in basic profile or full profile.For others you need to pass like "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url)" which ever you want from profile fields.http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields